# Which is fastest hash code that I can use to verify two identical data?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I want to check whether two data has same value so i am using CRC32 is it good than other hash functions. I don't require security. I am writing hash value in file and checking with another hash value to compare whether two buffer are same or not.

Comment: How large is the data? How rare should accidental collisions be? Does it need to be secure? How fast do you need to be?

Comment: Your question is shorter than title, can you please elaborate what are you asking. Current phrasing doesn't show how is the cryptography involved. In fact your question read out as "how to check whether two sequences of something are equal by value". If the scope of your problem is bigger, for instance having to find duplicate sequences among dozen, thousand or billion sequences than you have different significantly problem.

Comment: I don't require security. I am writing hash value in file and checking with another hash value to compare whether two buffer(Data) are same or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. CRC32 is not a cryptographically strong function.
2. Running through the data to calculate hash, then comparing hashes has the same speed as comparing data blocks themselves. And comparing data blocks guarantees the result, while any hashing doesn't (there's always room for collision with hashes). When it comes to comparing an existing hash with new data, hashing can be faster of course.

Comment: You mean that calculating CRC32 and checking with other data hash value is faster than checking with other data

Comment: @user2182934 Of course if you have a pre-computed hash of the data you compare (at least original data), then you need to calculate at most one hash for comparison. This operation is faster than comparing two pieces of data. In this case you can use almost any popular algorithm (SHA256 is fine) - they take only fraction of time needed to read the data from the storage.

Answer (score 1):

CRC32 is not a crypto hash function.  It's a simple checksum, and not much more.  What are you trying to do, and how secure does it need to be?